# how to assign datetimepicker to this label using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
 <label for="Date">
            dateformate:
            <span id="date-<%=Model.ID%>"><%=Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date)%></span>
        </label>
```

I need to assign datetimepicker for this lable? when any user clicks on the date label datetimepciker should popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the JQuery UI [Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/).

Your case is a bit special since the ID is generated dynamically but it is still pretty easy:

```
$("span[id^='date-']").datepicker();
```

Taking a closer look, I just realized that you are trying to tie the datepicker to a span where it would normally be assigned to a textbox.  So really what you are going to want is to add a textbox and then do this:

```
$("input[id^='date-']").datepicker();
```

Also make sure that you have the jQuery UI CSS referenced.  Something like this on your page or site.master:

```
@import url(/Content/ui.all.css);
```

Comment: Yes I did that.. but problem is after choosing date from datpicker when I am want to clear the date i am not able to clear the date its showing me previous date which I was selected..

thanks

Comment: THanks for your response I updated like this..

 $("span[id^='date-']").datepicker({
            duration: '',
            showTime: true,
            constrainInput: true,
            stepMinutes: 15,
            stepHours: 1,
            altTimeField: '',
            time24h: false,
            minDate: 0
        });

Comment: But still havig problem..
I am not getting Datepicker pop up window?

Comment: Are you missing a reference to the CSS file for jQuery UI?

Comment: Yes but I am geting two textboxes after removing span from there and I am not able to clear the textbox if i dont want date to be selected.that Is I am not able to make null textbox?

 <label for="Date">
           DateForMate:
            <input id="exc-followup-<%=Model.ID%>" /><%=Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date)%>
        </label>

Comment: Are you saying that you want to clear the input after you have selected a date?

Comment: Well....the user could just clear the input manually, or you could create a clear button to do it.

Comment: the user can not able to celar the input manually if he is its showing the same date which user selected previously..

thanks